# A question I got from an 8 years old kid:

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I got this one from an 8 old kid who got this at school

Can you get the number in the right by using the numbers on the left with the rules:

1. Each number should be used 1 time exactly,
2. The allowed operations are: $(,),+,-,\cdot,/$

A solved exercise as an example:

> $12$ $11$ $20$ $2$ $= 9$ solution: $(20/2)-(12-11)$

Any ideas regarding the solutions of these three?

> $8$ $2$ $1$ $32$ $= 31$

> $11$ $2$ $1$ $9$ $= 111$

For example, to me it seems like the first one has no solution.
I can explain it intuitively to myself but I can't prove it formally.
Am I right? If yes, is there a way to formally proof it?

Thanks!

*Edit* exponentials and roots are not allowed (i.e. $8^2$ is not allowed). All the numbers must be used.
No concatenation is allowed.

Comment: Can we use exponentiation?

Comment: Is it necessary to use all numbers !?

Comment: Allowing also exponentiation we have: $8^2-1-32=31$, $11^2- 1- 9 = 111$. The third one would also work well for $5$ as a result.

Comment: Last one: 5-(9+2)/11=4

Comment: Suggestion: you can ask this question in stack overflow. One can definitely make a program with any programming language such as python to calculate all possible expressions and compare them with RHS

Comment: $(8+1)×3+(2×2)=...$

Comment: Can we concatenate digits to make a larger number like making 1000 with eight 8's using 888+88+8+8+8?

Comment: no concatenation is allowed, also, in the first exercise, the last number is 32 (not 3 and 2)

Comment: How about ${11\choose 9}2 +1=111$? Using the parentheses for combination, i.e., $^{11}C_9$. Don't tell me brackets weren't allowed. :) 8 yr old, I got you!

Comment: :)) its not the brackets but their meaning... Those kids have learned only the basic operations. They didn't study exponentials or "p choose n"-like things. I am curious if this can be done with just basic operations (the brackets are for the right order of operations.. )

Comment: Yeah yeah. I know. I too tried many different possible expressions using the 4 basic operations only for first and second but never got them equal to RHS. I seems to me that they have no solutions (The truth value of this hypothesis can be checked using any computer programming language) and if they actually have no solution then a formal proof for that should exist. You might want to edit or post another question asking for formal proof if the hypothesis is true.

Comment: I agree with you.. I think there is no solution for the first one. I posted this question in stackoverflow and in mathoverflow and they deleted it (without answering the question). If you are familiar with any math forum or programming forum that could be suitable I'll be happy to know..  thanks :)

Comment: Is $11**2-(1+9)=111$ allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [some code to brute-force this](https://ideone.com/1vav7Q) instead of doing any hard thinky thinking. Neither {8 2 1 32} = 31 nor {11 2 1 9} = 111 have solutions. If 111 was a typo for 11, $11 + (9+2) \cdot 1$ works.

Answer (score 2):

For the third we have: $$5-(2+9):11=4.$$

Comment: nice, thank you

Comment: Very nice Michael!

Comment: As an alternative for the third one (same idea):
$$5-(11-9)/2$$

Comment: 5-(11-2)/9 indeed

Answer (score 0):

A formal way to prove it could be done [by exhaustion](http://As%20an%20alternative%20for%20the%20third%20one%20%20%7B419a822e-33e1-4749-b6a5-bbf431dd8e7a%7D) trying for all the possible allowed combinations of numbers and operations, similarly to what they did for the first proof of the famous "[Four colour theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)", using a calculator.

Comment: I wonder why you put the sentence "as an alternative..." in a link. But it's fun to crack that :P

Comment: @Trebor It is an alternative to the answer given by Michael!